# Changed files are not modified?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have checked out a directory from my local SVN: server. After changing some file I want to commit the changes. Here I get the problem:

- In TortoiseSVN the files are marked as changed (red icon).
- TortoiseSVN commit says 'No file were changed or added...'
- TotoiseSVN update changes nothing.
- `svn stat` does not list the files as modified.
- `svn cat` shows an obviously diffent content than the file in working copy
- `svn diff` does not show any difference
- `svn update` tells me `At revision 156.`
- TortoiseSVN repo browser shows that the file in repository is at revision 153.

`svn stat hello.js` shows this:

```
Path: hello.js
Name: hello.js
URL: svn:///Projects/Sample/hello.js
Repository Root: svn:///Projects
Repository UUID: 2e99062c-3216-5d44-9338-d29899e4dc4b
Revision: 156
Node Kind: file
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Rev: 153
Last Changed Date: 2011-06-13 10:45:42 +0200 (Mon, 13 Jun 2011)
Text Last Updated: 2011-06-13 09:54:07 +0200 (Mon, 13 Jun 2011)
Checksum: 4fed4d6472b30096cd00f8e1229ff833
```

The Last Updated date is identical with the file date in working copy.

How do I convince SVN to commit the changes?

Comment: It's likely that TortoiseSVN uses last modified time stamp on a file to display the red icon. SVN in general, only commits files, when there is an actual change in the file, i.e. svn diff will yield at least something. Not that I know, but I suspect you don't actually have those files modified, that's why they won't commit. If you absolutely insist on committing a file, add an empty line at the top or the bottom, and/or try setting a bogus SVN property on a file.

Comment: Did you use any automated tools to modify the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reinstalled SVN and the problem vanished. Unfortunately I had not the time to investigate further.

Answer (score 2):

There's 2 things going on here. Firstly, the icons are drawn using TSVNCache.exe which sits in the background watching for filesystem changes and updating the icons accordingly. However, its not as good as it used to be and so doesn't display the correct icon all the time. Add to that, Windows is pretty bad at helping it along, especially in the tree part of explorer, so there are quite a few times when the icon overlays are just wrong and stay wrong. I find the easiest way to fix this is to stop TSVNCache (using task manager). It is safe to stop, and it will automatically restart.
Hopefully Microsoft will fix explorer so this functionality can work more reliably.

The 2nd part is that, despite the icon showing red, the file really has not changed - you can see this because the svn diff reports no differences! (Tortoise can tell you exactly the same info by using its 'check for modifications' command).

I'd be interested to know why svn cat shows 'obviously different content' yet svn diff does not.

Comment: Stopping TSVNCache does seem to work, but I also had to open a new instance of Windows Explorer to get the tree icons to display properly.

Answer (score 1):

As for the revision number, if I remember correctly, it shows the last revision where that particular file was modified. So the fact that the SVN file is on revision 153 and your local code is on revision 156 just means that the file wasn't changed in the last 3 revisions.

If you do check it in and then look at the file history, you'll see the revision numbers jump from 153 to 156.

`diff` is usually quite picky/thorough by default, marking even single space differences as modified - if it's not picking anything up I'd say trust it. But make sure you're actually diffing (I like that word) between the correct versions (HEAD/working copy, most likely).

I'd be interested to see the root of this problem, if you do figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

Open you project->Right click
Click on Disconnect then Do the usual work like share project using SVN and commit it.